# Swift Array returning empty after leaving function

Tags: arrays, swift, api, semaphore

When running the code below, returning `coordsArray` returns no value when outside of the `getCrimes` function, but prints a value when inside. I read online about using something called a semaphore but have no experience in that so was hoping someone could guide me on this and how to correctly return `coordsArray`

```
func getCrimes(completion: @escaping ([Crime])->()){
    //guard let crimeURL = URL(string: "https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/drugs?poly=51.5623,-2.5709:51.4952,-2.7292:51.4008,-2.6235:51.4028,-2.4875:51.4569,-2.4274&date=\(currentYear)-\(currentMonth)") else {return}
    guard let crimeURL = URL(string: "https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/drugs?poly=51.5623,-2.5709:51.4952,-2.7292:51.4008,-2.6235:51.4028,-2.4875:51.4569,-2.4274&date=2022-02") else {return}
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: crimeURL) { (data, _, _) in
        let crimes = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Crime].self, from: data!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            completion(crimes)
        }
    }
    .resume()
}

func getLocations() -> [Coords] {
    var coordsArray : [Coords] = []
    getCrimes{ (crimes) in
        self.crimes = crimes
        for crime in crimes{
            let lat = Double(crime.location.latitude)!
            let long = Double(crime.location.longitude)!
            coordsArray.append(Coords(latitude:lat, longitude: long))
        }
        print(coordsArray) //Does display the array
    }
    print(coordsArray)//Doesn't display the array
    return coordsArray //Blank Array
}
```

Comment: You are missing th asynchrone concept. `getCrimes(completion:)` is async like `dataTask(with:completion:)`. Why did you use an escaping closure  in `getCrimes`? It's the same logic to use for `getLocation()`. Don't try to use a semaphore, just handle the same way the asynchronism. You could use `async`/`await` in recent Swift, the way of handling asynchrone is different, but it'ts still asynchrone.

Answer (score 0):

You execute a async function in main thread. Main thread will not wait for that async thread, it continues to execute next command in function.

```
func getLocations() -> [Coords] {
    // Main Thread
    var coordsArray : [Coords] = []
    
    getCrimes { (crimes) in
        // Async Thread, suppose 100ms to complete
        self.crimes = crimes
        for crime in crimes{
            let lat = Double(crime.location.latitude)!
            let long = Double(crime.location.longitude)!
            coordsArray.append(Coords(latitude:lat, longitude: long))
        }
        print(coordsArray)
    }
    
    
    // Main thread, very fast, execute immediately after execute `getCrimes`, 
    // => coordsArray = [] because Async Task not complete
    print(coordsArray)
    return coordsArray
}
```

You can wait at main thread, but it shouldn't be use because it lock main and UI will stop

```
func getCrimes(completion: @escaping ([Crime])->()){
    //guard let crimeURL = URL(string: "https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/drugs?poly=51.5623,-2.5709:51.4952,-2.7292:51.4008,-2.6235:51.4028,-2.4875:51.4569,-2.4274&date=\(currentYear)-\(currentMonth)") else {return}
    guard let crimeURL = URL(string: "https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/drugs?poly=51.5623,-2.5709:51.4952,-2.7292:51.4008,-2.6235:51.4028,-2.4875:51.4569,-2.4274&date=2022-02") else {return}
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: crimeURL) { (data, _, _) in
        let crimes = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Crime].self, from: data!)
        
        // The main thread was lock, so need execute completion at other thread
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async{
            completion(crimes)
        }
    }
    .resume()
}

func getLocations() -> [Coords] {
    var coordsArray : [Coords] = []
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    
    getCrimes{ (crimes) in
        self.crimes = crimes
        for crime in crimes{
            let lat = Double(crime.location.latitude)!
            let long = Double(crime.location.longitude)!
            coordsArray.append(Coords(latitude:lat, longitude: long))
        }
        print(coordsArray) //Does display the array
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    dispatchGroup.wait() // Lock thread until complete async task
    print(coordsArray)//Doesn't display the array
    return coordsArray //Blank Array
}
```

Instead of, you can use escaping closure

```
func getLocations(completeGetLocation: (([Coords]) -> Void)?) {
    var coordsArray : [Coords] = []
    getCrimes { (crimes) in
        self.crimes = crimes
        for crime in crimes{
            let lat = Double(crime.location.latitude)!
            let long = Double(crime.location.longitude)!
            coordsArray.append(Coords(latitude:lat, longitude: long))
        }
        print(coordsArray) //Does display the array
        completeGetLocation?(coordsArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, just tried this, but the escaping closure causes an issue on another line when using `getLocations` saying: `Missing argument for parameter 'completeGetLocation' in call.` And when completeGetLocation is added it says it cannot convert value?